Textfields in the app crash the entire program
I have a flutter app and each time I try to type on real device in a text field it makes my app crash , any idea ? any solution to these? I give some example, here is my bottom sheet for edit profile for user , it displays his work schedule and name from Firestore , I try to modify the textfields - crash:
children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: _userNameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Username",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    TextField(
                      controller: openTimeController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Opening Time",
                        hintText: "e.g., 09:00",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    TextField(
                      controller: closeTimeController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Closing Time",
                        hintText: "e.g., 17:00",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    TextField(
                      controller: workingDaysController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Working Days",
                        hintText: "e.g., Monday-Friday",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 24),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: darkBlueColor,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _saveChanges();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Save Changes',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),


Some points for debugging: (1) does it happen for any of the TextFields or just one? (2) Can you reproduce it with a smaller example?

Does it work ok in the emulator? What is the physical device?

You get a error stack trace?

It happens to any textfield in the app

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/16872
